# Отфильровать дочерние элементы, содержащие текст и изменить размер шрифта

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте. 
Есть элемент:

```
<div class="wrapper">
тут много всяких дочерних элементов, в том чисел вложенных друг в друга
</div>
```

Как мне с помощью jquery получить только те потомки (в том числе вложенные) #wrapper, которые содержат текст (не важно какой, лишь бы текст) и изменить для них размер шрифта?

Спасибо.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378620/jquery-find-if-element-has-any-text

Comment: $(this).text() не работает так как нужно. Он выбирает и элементы с текстом внутри и всех их предков.

Comment: Не совсем понятно как вы себе представляете изменении шрифта. Если вы укажите какие либо изменения для родителя то дети унаследуют их. Если текст обернут каким либо тегом, то это как то проще. Есть возможность изменить разметку, или она и так другая?) Возможно более точный пример дал бы больше понимания.

Comment: Вы хотите применить изменения не принимая во внимание родитель это или дети?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил так

```
$(".wrapper *").each(function(){
if ($(this).text().trim().length) {
    $(this).addClass("right");
}});
```

но у подхода есть минусы. И первый же минус в том, что он добавит класс даже туда, где нет текста, но есть дочерний элемент с текстом. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ovzfvrgk/1/
P.S. Заметил комментарии - он по сути отвечает на тот же вопрос

Правка:

```
$(".wrapper *").each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var isParent= element.get(0).childElementCount>0;
    if (element.text().trim().length && !isParent) {
        element.addClass("right");
    } 
});
```

Если я правильно тебя понял, то вот такой вариант должен помочь - он не будет помечать родительский блок.

http://jsfiddle.net/ovzfvrgk/5/

Comment: Если было так просто не спрашивал был :) 
Конечно же $(this).text() - это проблема. Он мне увеличивает шрифт и элементам с текстом внутри и всем их родителям всех степеней вложенности.